# NGINX SPDY client differentiation/determination

Tags: nginx, ssl, spdy

I'm having a question about determining if a client is capable of SPDY or just SSL. I'm having a setup of a NGINX load balancer and a few Apache backend servers and I'd like to redirect SPDY capable clients to specific backends, as well as redirect "SSL only" clients to another backends. Is there a way to determine something like this?

Comment: There is variable [`$spdy`](http://nginx.org/r/$spdy)

Answer (score 0):

There's $spdy variable that you can check... it contains the protocol version (2 or 3 currently supported in Nginx I think).

[Module ngx_http_spdy_module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_spdy_module.html#variables)